# require files across dozens of pages with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a site with a few dozen pages that are php and use ajax to make calls all over the place.  These pages require a few files that contain specific commands used across these pages.

it would be simple to just require them in each page.  however, I would like to have 1 page that has all the requirments.  If I have to make a change at anytime, I don't want to have to go through and change every page's requires,  so i thought about having a requires.php with all the requirements, and then just call that page.  however, when i call a script with ajax, the directory location for that requires.php is going to be different.  so i would have to have a separate location for that requires call and I end up in the same place.  I hope this isn't confusing. Ill try to diagram it:

requires.php

```
 $login = "/var/www/lib/login.php";
```

home.php

```
  require('requires.php');
  ///some code
    require($login);


 ///some ajax call to /actions/settings/docs/action.php
```

/actions/settings/docs/action.php

```
 //some stuff
 require(?????); <-- requires.php isn't in same directory
```

Comment: so use absolute path server side. You could still use variable for your absolute path

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
require( '../../../require.php' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to set your include path https://www.php.net/set_include_path

```
$path = '/your/path';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
```

Comment: would i have to set $path on every page or once?

Comment: @bart2puck you would have to set it on every page, or you could set it via your .htaccess file